# Changing background color when the page is loaded

Tags: html, css

Once I go on the element which holds `screen-transition` class, 
the following code just turns the background color from transparent
 to green through `hover`:

```
.screen-transition{
        position: relative;
        display: block !important;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .screen-transition::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: green;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: 1s;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .screen-transition:hover::before {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

and now I just want to replace `hover` with sth else so that background color turns to green when the page is loaded

any workaround please?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the body of the page in the css file?

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: then what about transition??

Answer (score 0):

If you want this fadeIn to happen on page Load, simply define a keyframe and add the animation to before class. Let me know if this works

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { 
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.screen-transition{
        position: relative;
        display: block !important;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .screen-transition::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: green;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: 1s;
      animation: fadeIn 2s;
    }
```

Comment: it somehow works but after `2s` the background goes away.
actually after the time set in `animation`.
how to get it permanent?

Comment: Oh remove opacity: 0 from the before class. Edited the answer. Try again

Answer (score 0):

js code

```
document.body.onload=function ()
{
     setTimeout(function() 
      {document.body.classList.add('animation_class')},1000);
}
```

CSS code

```
. animatin_class
{
   background-color:green ! important;
}
body
{
   background-color:red;
  transition:all .4s;
 }
```